# How to get length of a stream writer in java

Tags: java, streamwriter

In java is there any functionality equivalent to below c# code for getting stream length.

```
StreamWriter.BaseStream.Length
```

I have searched on internet and also I checked the properties of "BufferredWriter", "OutputStreamWriter" and "FileOutputStream" but I did not find anything. Any information is appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think that e.g. `InputStream` has `available` parameters. But sometimes is returns not correct value.

Comment: What would that even be? A stream doesn't have a length. Maybe you could explain to us Java folks what the meaning of a stream length in C# is?

Comment: @MaxVollmer Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length(v=vs.110).aspx It's the number of bytes in the stream.

Comment: I have edited the code line. By mistake I had written "StreamLength" instead of "StreamWriter".

Comment: Where does the data you want to write come from ?

Comment: I still don't really understand what this length is supposed to be. I mean a stream specifically avoids having a fixed size, otherwise it wouldn't be a stream, but a buffer. Is this the size of the buffer backing the stream? But not every stream uses a buffer.

Comment: @Berger Data in stream will come from file with which stream is created.

Comment: `length()` will give you the number of bytes of a `File`.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you describe what you actually want to achieve, i.e. what you need that length for and how you create your stream, and then we can tell you how to do it in Java. Best to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @Berger : Yes, but here the situation is like, you need to check the current no. of bytes in the stream (file info will not be available at that location of code). and based upon length next code execution is decided.

Comment: *"you need to check the current no. of bytes in the stream and based upon length next code execution is decided"* Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to use File.length() property as I found no way to get length from stream like C#.

Here is how it was done:

Note (using flag etc.) which file the stream is associated with.

When you need the length of stream, just get File.Length for the file which you had associated with stream like below.

Why I needed to check length is to prevent writing to file more than defined max length.

```
                String sFilePath = this.m_sLogFolderPath + File.separator;
                if(this.m_File2Active == true)
                {
                    sFilePath += Def.DEF_FILE2;
                }
                else
                {
                    sFilePath += Def.DEF_FILE1;
                }
                File file = new File(sFilePath);
                if(file.length() > this.m_lMaxSize)
                {
                    this.m_bwWriter.flush();
                    this.m_bwWriter.close();
                    this.m_bwWriter = null;
                    sFilePath = this.m_sLogFolderPath + File.separator;
                    if (this.m_File2Active == true)
                    {
                        sFilePath += Def.DEF_FILE1;
                        this.m_File2Active = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sFilePath += Def.DEF_FILE2;
                        this.m_File2Active = true;
                    }
                    this.m_bwWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sFilePath, true), Def.DEF_ENCODING_UTF8));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

An `OutputStream` has finally the length of the content which **YOU** write into the stream.